# Parsing only the id with regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, k6

Using this regex `/var userId = (\d+)/`, I can find the id of the user. Except it returns `"var userId = 117051"` instead of just 117051. I looked around in regexr but I'm not very good with regex. Is there a way to only get the id?

Comment: Are you parsing javascript with regexp?

Comment: Extract the value from the first capturing group. `var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]);`

Comment: @Shilly I'm using regex in javascript

Comment: Your regex already works correctly. You just need to access Group 1 value using the right code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string = "some string containing var userId = 117051";
var foundId = string.match(/var userId = (\d+)/)[1];
console.log(foundId); // "117051"
```